# Pay as you go with Paypal

Tags: paypal

I want to implement a pay as you go with Paypal, as I read the [subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions) API we need to create a **plan** and **product**, and as I understand it, it works based on the regular payments which obviously we don't want that we want if the user's budget is below a certain amount we recharge the user by a fixed amount again, can anybody guide me how to approach and implement *pay as go* using Paypal?

Comment: Sorry, but your question reads like it was written by a 1 day newbie, not a member of 10 years. Maybe you should revisit the [help] to remind yourself how/what to ask here. This question here is low quality on so many different levels.

Comment: Because in the end, you are asking a "someone help me with X" ... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question#:~:text=So%20therefore%20we%20need%20to,to%20solve%20their%20own%20problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, subscriptions bill on a regular schedule whereas what you are describing is the ability to bill an arbitrary amount at any time.

That feature is called "reference transactions", or sometimes "billing agreements". It is not enabled for PayPal business accounts by default. To request the feature, the owner of the PayPal account should contact PayPal's general business support (note: not technical support) and explain the business need for this reference transactions feature.

If it's approved for the account, PayPal can then guide you on which API integration to use; potentially something like the newest v2/vault.